# What tags do we have related to [the-netherlands]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

As a Dutch citizen, I like to follow tags related to The Netherlands. As such, I think an overview of all tags related to The Netherlands may come in handy, not just for me.

So far, I've found [netherlands](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands), [dutch-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-citizens), [dutch-language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-language), [dutch-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-residents), [amsterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsterdam), and [rotterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotterdam). Can we compile a comprehensive list of tags related to The Netherlands?

Comment: [tulips] [orange] [bicyclephilia] [direct-answers] [tall-blondes] [superfrugality] [wooden-shoes] [windmill-life]. Is that all the stereotypes? Maybe something about cheese? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*CW answer, please keep up to date.*</sup>

### The Netherlands

- [netherlands](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netherlands)
- [dutch-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-citizens)
- [dutch-language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-language)
- [dutch-residents](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dutch-residents)

### Countries, Provinces, Regions, and Cities in The Netherlands

- [aruba](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aruba)
- [amsterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsterdam)
- [eindhoven](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eindhoven)
- [rotterdam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rotterdam)

### Transport

- [ams](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ams) (Amsterdam Airport Schiphol)
- [ein](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ein) (Eindhoven Airport)
- [mst](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mst) (Maastricht Aachen Airport)
- [rtm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rtm) (Rotterdam The Hague Airport)
- [klm](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/klm) (Royal Dutch Airlines)
- [nederlandse-spoorwegen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nederlandse-spoorwegen) (Dutch Railways)